# Should threadlocal declared as a final field

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, final, thread-local

When programming using ThreadLocal class, should the field declared final?
if write code like `private ThreadLocal<String> threadLocal` and initialize it in constructor later, since the variable threadLocal reference cannot be changed any more, I guess it's equal to `private final ThreadLocal<String> threadLocal;` is this  idea right?What is the difference between the following method in a multi-threading class?

```
 public class ThreadLocalTestForMultiThread{
        private ThreadLocal<String> threadLocal;
        public ThreadLocalTestForMultiThread(){
            threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<String>();
        }
    }

    public class ThreadLocalTestForMultiThread{
        private final ThreadLocal<String> threadLocal;
        public ThreadLocalTestForMultiThread(){
            threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<String>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your second example shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @Codebender, yeah, you are right,did not considerably thought of it

Comment: Since your are new here don't not forget the accept a answer, whenever it helped most. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottomline is that you don't have to have `final` on `ThreadLocal` but you would most likely have not just `final` but also `static` on it.

When you are working on `ThreadLocal` variables, the noticeable key attribute is such variable would have an instance per thread. Also, you must provide an implementation to the `initialValue()` method so that the class knows how to construct a new object when needed.

Note that when you have a normal class level variable, it's implicit that such variable would have a copy as per instance. In the real world you won't have too much applications to have a `ThreadLocal` as per instance; and most likely you have it on the `class` level, that is, `static`. In this way it's almost sure to have it initialized in a `static` block or immediately.

Comment: if write code like private ThreadLocal<String> threadLocal and initialize it in constructor later, since the variable threadLocal reference cannot be changed any more, I guess it's equal to private final ThreadLocal<String> threadLocal; is this idea right?

Answer (score 0):

Using `final` or `static` on a `ThreadLocal` variable is driven by the same thoughts like using them on any other variable.

1. When to use `final`?

The `final` keyword is used for a variable which can be only assigned once. And in case of a global one it has to be assigned directly at declaration or in the constructor.
In case of a `ThreadLocal` this make in 99% cases sense. Because normally, you won't change the ThreadLocal instance you will only change the referenced `Object` through `ThreadLocal#set(T value)`.

2. When to use `static`?

A `static` variable is associated to the owning `Class` and not to an `Object`. That means all instances of a `Class` sharing the same `static` variable.
If a `ThreadLocal` is declared as `static` this `ThreadLocal` variable (and also the references of the `ThreadLocal`) is shared by all `Objects` of the owning `Class`.